# String tokenize on pipe when double pipe character exists

Tags: regex, groovy

I have a String that contains '||' and '|' and I want to tokenise it only on the '|'

For example:

```
|A||This is some string|B||This is some other String
```

Should be tokenised to

```
[A||This is some string, B||This is some other String]
```

I've tried using `val.tokenize('\\|')` but that does not give me the desired result i.e. it tokenises on the '||' as well and I get:

```
[A, This is some string, B, This is some other String]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

PS: I am using Groovy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [lookaround](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookarounds) assertions.

```
def s = '|A||This is some string|B||This is some other String'
def m = s.split('(?<!\\|)\\|(?!\\|)')
println m.findAll {it != ''}
```

Although it's shorter to do:

```
def m = s.findAll('[^|]+\\|{2}[^|]+')
assert m == ['A||This is some string', 'B||This is some other String']
```

Output

```
[A||This is some string, B||This is some other String]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as intended. I didn't know about lookaround assertions really, so thanks for that info too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
(?<!\|)\|(?!\|)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/xZ2hY7/2)**

Remember to use double backslashes as:

```
(?<!\\|)\\|(?!\\|)
```

[image]

Comment: `\b\|\b` won't match `|A`. Maybe `^\|\b|\b\|\b|\b\|$` ?